# Cisco ASA Static NAT RULE Problem

Tags: cisco, nat

I need to clarify a one of cisco asa NAT rule. i searched lot and still not found a clear answer. please see below rule
•

> nat (Inside,Outside) source static any any destination static
>   NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.24_29 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.24_29 no-proxy-arp
>   route-lookup

object NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.24_29 is contain same ip.

What is the reason for using same IP at the destination part?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: can you please explain why its using same ip address for destination part?